# How to view tables in sas 9.4 in sasoprsk library

Tags: sas, sas-macro, sas-metadata

I have a sas server of EGRC 6.1 module and I can't see the tables in sasoprsk library after running autoexe in sas 9.4

After runing autoexe it start showing libraries in explorer tab of sas 9.5 but it didn't show the tables of sasoprsk library

**Things I've tried**:

- I've restarted the server
- I restarted the services
- I run to connect db_connect and db_libname

How can I see all the tables of Sasoprsk library in sas 9.4 after submitting autoexe file from ucmacros folder.

Comment: sas 9.5? Maybe typo or are you pointing to wrong path?

Comment: @pinegulf I can't see the tables. Everything else is working fine